# using ubuntu to fix windows

Tags: windows-7

I dual booted Ubuntu along side windows 7 because the keyboard and mouse on my laptop had stopped responding. Both work perfect while using Ubuntu so, could I use some of the drivers from Ubuntu to help fix windows?

Comment: You should survey your question in Windows related forums. It will appreciated if you ask this on http://superuser.com/ . You can find your answer there.

Comment: I believe this to be on topic. He is asking for a solution from within Ubuntu. That there is none does not invalidate the question (but if anyone disagrees that is fine with me ;) )

Answer (score 3):

No, this is impossible.

From Ubuntu you can ...

- delete Windows
- repair the filesystem up to an extent.
- copy files from and to it that are not system files.

Anything related to installing, drivers, registry, system files is not possible or breaks the integrity of Windows. Basically anything that requires registry changes is impossible too: Windows will not accept those changes when you boot it and if you are unlucky will even end up with BSODs or what ever is the current equivalent.

To fix Windows you need either the installation disc to repair or re-install or you need a working Windows if it concerns drivers or other things.

Comment: I don't think Windows could run an Ubuntu driver anyway because of kernel differences, no?

Comment: Windows? That is the other way around ;) @seth but no... that is impossible too.